# Responsive webdesign stylesheet - single vs multiple files

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm currently studying different methods of optimising my soon-to-be-launched html5 responsive  website. I ended up looking at Andy Clarke's *[320 and up project](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/)*, which I find quite interesting.

Although this looks like a pretty neat idea to improve loading times on mobile browsers, I fail to completely figure out what to choose between putting all the media queries in one big css file, or splitting them into different files for different screen widths thresholds.

As I see it up until now, in either case I'm not able to optimise the stylesheets as much as I'd like. Here are the scenarios:

1. I put all the media queries in one big css file. Although the relevant code for mobile browsers is only in the first quarter of the file, the file gets downloaded completely, thus wasting quite some bandwidth.
2. I split the stylesheet into multiple files (i.e. will have 320.css, 480.css, 786.css and so on), and declare each of them in the header with something along ths line of
   `<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 480px)" ...`
   In this particular case, mobile browsers will only download their relevant file, but computer browsers might get a hit in performance (which I can't really quantify at the moment) due to the multiple get requests to handle all the css files matching their screen width.

What's your take on this? I already know that I'll end up making a compromise. The bottom line question would be *"which one?"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I determined by measuring my particular code that avoiding HTTP requests was better than downloading extra gzipped CSS.

Use something like http://www.webpagetest.org/ to test both versions, this will give you a good idea of what's going on.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the right answer depends on your exact code as well as the time it takes an HTTP connection to be set up to your server.